# I'm not getting EditText Value in another class

Tags: java, android, android-layout

**MainActivity.java (First Class)**

```
package com.example.we.reportcardjavaclass;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public EditText one, two, three, four, five, six;
    public String bang1, bang2, bang3, bang4, bang5, bang6;
    public Button results;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // Find the View that shows the numbers category

    }

    public void getResult(View view){
        results = (Button) findViewById(R.id.result);
        Intent numbersIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, result.class);
        startActivity(numbersIntent);
        one = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
        bang1 = one.getText().toString();

        two = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Class);
        bang2 = two.getText().toString();

        three = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.English);
        bang3 = three.getText().toString();

        four = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Hindi);
        bang4 = four.getText().toString();

        five = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Maths);
        bang5 = five.getText().toString();

        six = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Science);
        bang6 = six.getText().toString();

    }

}
```

**activity_main.xml (First Layout File)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.we.reportcardjavaclass.MainActivity"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Student's Name"
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Class"
        android:id="@+id/Class"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Grade in English"
        android:id="@+id/English"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="128dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Grade in Hindi"
        android:id="@+id/Hindi"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="192dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Grade in Maths"
        android:id="@+id/Maths"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="256dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Grade in Science"
        android:id="@+id/Science"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="320dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp" />

    <Button
        android:text="Get result"
        android:id="@+id/result"
        android:onClick="getResult"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="384dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"/>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>








## result.xml (Second Layout File) ##

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="32dp">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/resultCard"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        card_view:cardElevation="2dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingBottom="20dp"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:paddingTop="20dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                    android:text="Student's Name"
                    android:textAllCaps="true"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/one"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"

                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:textStyle="normal"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                    android:text="Class"
                    android:textAllCaps="true"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/two"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:textStyle="normal"/>

            </LinearLayout>


            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="160dp"
                android:background="@color/cardview_dark_background"
                android:padding="20dp"
                >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:text="English"
                    android:textAllCaps="true"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/three"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"

                    android:textAllCaps="true"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textStyle="normal"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                    android:text="Hindi"
                    android:textAllCaps="true"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/four"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"

                    android:textAllCaps="true"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textStyle="normal"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
                    android:text="Maths"
                    android:textAllCaps="true"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/five"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="80dp"

                    android:textAllCaps="true"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textStyle="normal"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
                    android:text="Science"
                    android:textAllCaps="true"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/six"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="120dp"

                    android:textAllCaps="true"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textStyle="normal"/>

            </RelativeLayout>
            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="350dp"
                android:text="BACK TO HOME"
                />
        </FrameLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout></ScrollView>
```

**Second Class**

```
package com.example.we.reportcardjavaclass;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * Created by we on 08-07-2017.
 */

public class result extends MainActivity{

    public TextView one, two, three, four, five, six;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.result);
        setTitle(bang1+"s Result");
        one = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.one);
        one.setText(bang1);
        two = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.two);
        two.setText(bang2);
        three = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.three);
        three.setText(bang3);
        four = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.four);
        four.setText(bang4);
        five = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.five);
        five.setText(bang5);
        six = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.six);
        six.setText(bang6);
    }
}
```

EditText values are getting stored MainActivity.java in variables bang - 123456. I added public modifier while declaring them so I can access these in second class too. In second class I want to use these variable values to set in into Textviews but while running it is not showing the value.

I have also attached the screenshots of both layouts after running in my emulator.

- [Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zpCt0.png)
- [Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NEBw0.png)

In second layout it is supposed to show name and other values.

Comment: You can access the variables in other activities if you make them `static`. For eg, replace `public String bang1, bang2, bang3, bang4, bang5, bang6;` with `public static String bang1, bang2, bang3, bang4, bang5, bang6;`. and then in your other activity, you can call it as `MainActivity.bang1`,`MainActivity.bang2`,`MainActivity.bang3` etc. Just give a try..

Comment: @Lal: This is a very bad idea for a number of reasons. It will break when there are multiple instances of MainActivity (think of launching a new task from a notification) and will not work when resuming your application from a saved instance state. Worse yet, is you're holding a static reference to an activity and thereby introduce a memory leak.

Comment: Honestly, I think you need to do some more research on Android fundamentals before you attempt something like this, as your question shows that you really don't understand how Activities work. There are a lot of things wrong here. Have a look at [Building Your First App](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html) in the Android documentation, or look up some tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you take a few steps back and get a better understanding of Android's fundamentals, including Activities in general. Perhaps a good place to start, would be understanding the [Activity Lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html).

An answer to your question isn't very simple, because the way in which Android works is likely very different from your understanding.

In short, your second activity is a completely different instance of a class than the first. Extending the second from the first *does not mean* that the assigned variables are available to the second, it merely means that the class inherits the structure of its parent in the form of methods and fields.

You should instead be designing your activities in such a way that they relay those strings. When launching your second activity, include those strings in the intent when starting it.

For instance:

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // ...

    /** Your method where the second activity is launched */
    public void onButtonClicked() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
        intent.putString(SecondActivity.EXTRA_BANG1, bang1);
        // ...
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}

public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String EXTRA_BANG1 = "bang1";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.result);
        // ...
        TextView tvOne = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.one);
        // ...

        String bang1 = getIntent().getString(EXTRA_BANG1);
        tvOne.setText(bang1);
    }

}
```

I thoroughly recommend reading up in the Android documentation (it's excellently written!) to better understand how (and why) it works through this mechanism. In particular, [this article on *Sending data between activities*](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/parcelables-and-bundles.html) is very relevant to you.

Answer (score -2):

If you want to use these values in another activity then simply pass these values along with the intent that is used to start a new activity.

MainActivity.java

```
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
i.putExtra("Bang1",bang1);
i.putExtra("Bang2",bang2);
i.putExtra("Bang3",bang3);
...
```

And you can get them in the SecondActivity.java file as:

```
Intent i =getIntent();
int bang1 = i.getIntExtra("Bang1");
...
```

But instead so choosing the string names as shown i would suggest to create a new class to store the the string names as final string constants in order to avoid any kind of mistake.

Or you can directly declare these variables as static and access them in the SecondActivity by referring to their names as :

```
 int bang1 = MainActivity.bang1;
```